# Interesting opensource projects to contribute to as a sysadmin?

Tags: untagged

I know that as a sysadmin you can contribute to opensource projects such as a Debian and Fedora. Joining their infrastructure groups and help with administration. I'm just wondering if there are any other interesting opensource projects/communities. To which sysadmin with a free time can contribute and sharpen his skills.

Answer (score 4):

While a good question, the options are endless.  I tend to try to contribute to things I use and find useful, while focusing on projects that are especially in need of assistance.  Inprotect is a team that could definitely use some additional assistance.

- [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/) - Linux distribution. ([Debian](http://www.debian.org/), [Slackware](http://www.slackware.com/), and other distributions are acceptable as well.)
- [Inprotect](http://inprotect.sourceforge.net/) - Front end for Nessus, a vulnerability scanner.
- [SNORT](http://www.snort.org/) - A network IDS.
- [Request Tracker](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) - A very customizable ticket system.

Answer (score 2):

Monitoring products : OpenNMS, Nagios, MRTG, Orca, etc.